# How much air pressure in tires when storing a vehicle?

Tags: tires, long-term-storage, tire-pressure, storage

When storing a vehicle for several months to a year, is it better to have the tyres/tires overinflated a little, underinflated a little, or at their regular operating pressure?

Comment: Is it being stored weight on or weight off the tires?

Comment: Great question Mike.  Stored with weight on the tires.

Answer (score 2):

Please check YOUR tires for any differing details but Continental says this at:

[Continental Tire Customer Help](http://continentaltire.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/463/~/tire-storage)

> In cases where the tires will be supporting the vehicle, it is permissible to inflate the tires to the maximum pressure listed on the sidewall. Be sure to return the inflation pressure to recommended usage pressure before operating the vehicle.

This source, at least, does not give any specific recommendation for storage when the car's weight is supported by something else although the original question doesn't suggest that the car is going to be stored other than on its tires.  In that case, however, it's safe to assume that the NORMAL operating pressure for the tire is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks!  It's interesting that they use the word "permissible" instead of something like "preferable".  I'm not sure what to make of that.  Any ideas?